# pactree -r not showing all dependencies

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, manjaro

When I view which packages depend on the deprecated `webkitgtk2`, there are two:

```
genesis ~# pactree -r webkitgtk2 
webkitgtk2
└─pywebkitgtk
  └─manjaro-welcome
```

Where does the extra `manjaro-features-16.10-1` come from in the below?

```
genesis ~# pacman -Rncs webkitgtk2
checking dependencies...
:: gimp optionally requires webkitgtk2: for the help browser
:: wxgtk optionally requires webkitgtk2: for webview support

Packages (4) manjaro-features-16.10-1  manjaro-welcome-20161130-1  pywebkitgtk-1.1.8-4  webkitgtk2-2.4.11-4
```

Why isn't `pactree -r` showing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`manjaro-features` is a dependency of `manjaro-welcome`:

```
$ pactree -rs manjaro-features
manjaro-features
└─manjaro-welcome
```

As such, it is being removed by `-s`, quoting `man pacman`:

> Remove each target specified including all of their dependencies...